# Loss function to Push response value towards extremes

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, objective-functions, unsupervised-learning

I have a feature map whose values are in the range of [0,1]. I want to push these values either towards extreme 0 or 1 using some loss function. Since I don't have any target value so it had to be in unsupervised way. I want to visualize this feature map in a way that either pixels values are approaching 1 or 0. One possible technique is to use entropy loss. What are other possible techniques used in Loss function to get extreme pixel values?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem. Can you explain **why** you want to "push" the values of the feature map to 0 or 1?  So, is your goal only to see some kind of animation? It's also not clear how the entropy loss function would be used in your case. Can you provide more details about this?

Comment: So my goal is a sort of heat map where i could only highlight those pixels whose value is almost 1. Like GRAD-CAM shows the heatmap about which pixels are important in classification. Similarly i want the same heatmap for classification but only show either red(1) and blue(0) color so any pixel which is red would really contribute in the classification task